# Is there a way to customize firefox addons without actually touching the addon code?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'd like to extend an existing firefox addon with a feature that is very special to me (and therefore not relevant to other users of this addon).
How can I overwrite or hook into a javascript method without actually applying the changes to the addon's code?
Is there something like a special place where on can put additional files to be interpreted after the addon code?

Modifying the addon code itself would mean that my changes get lost everytime the addon is being updated.

Is there a general concept to achieve this?

EDIT for further information: The addon I am trying to extend is for customizing functionality and displayed information of a website on domReady. I want to change the addon's behavior to display even more special things.
For this purpose, I'd need my code to be executed after the addon code, but before the domReady event, i.e. using a bookmarklet won't work in this case.

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: I believe the general answer is basically "no", but there are many ways to interact with another extension (e.g. through XPCOM, by capturing observer notifications it might be sending out, by grabbing global variables it might expose). What exactly are you trying to do? More information might help.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - just updated the question with some more info. As there are global variables which would allow to overwrite the method, it is rather a problem of timing than a problem of access. I.e. to be executed after the addon code but before domReady event.

Comment: Oh great, an addon for an addon! Once you're done with that, I'm going to write an addon for your addon's addon!

Answer (score 0):

I would add your code and keep a backup of it so you can add it back after updates.

You can also create an addon that listens for when the addon code runs, maybe something like

```
function listener() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (document.getElementById('someId').style.prop === 'changed?') {
      startYourAddon();
    } else {
      listener(); //then there's a timeout, it would more logically fit around this call
    }
  }, 5);
}
listener();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution. You need to study the source code of the add-on and check which parts of it you want to extend and how it can be done. For example, the add-on you want to extend might define a browser window overlay and load its scripts there. It defines a function `MyExtension.doSomething()` that you would like to extend. You can do it by defining your own overlay and applying it to their overlay. E.g. their `chrome.manifest` contains the line:

```
overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://myextension/content/overlay.xul
```

You add the following to your own `chrome.manifest`:

```
overlay chrome://myextension/content/overlay.xul chrome://myextensionaddon/content/overlay.xul
```

Where `myextensionaddon` is the chrome namespace of your own add-on. And your overlay could run something similar to this code:

```
(function()
{
  // Store original method so that we can call it later
  var oldMethod = MyExtension.doSomething;

  // Replace the method by our own
  MyExtension.doSomething = function()
  {
    // Code executed before the original method is called goes here
    oldMethod.apply(this, arguments);
    // Code executed after the original method is called goes here
  };
})();
```

This works because scripts of all overlays execute in the same context, namely the context of the window they are overlaying. And applying an overlay to an overlay makes sure that your overlay loads after the overlay you are extending.

Now extending a method is not always possible. If there is absolutely no other solution you could use a trick to manipulate one of their files. For that you use the [`override` instruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Chrome_Registration#override) in your `chrome.manifest`. For example, you override the add-on's `script.js` file with your own:

```
override chrome://myextension/content/script.js chrome://myextensionaddon/content/script.js
```

Overriding chrome URLs works for exact URL matches only meaning that you will still be able to access the original script under `chrome://myextension/content/script.js?foo` (it is no longer an exact match because of the query sting but the query string has no effect on the content that you get). Your `script.js` file could look like this:

```
// Code executed before the original file is loaded goes here

// Load the original script now
Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"]
          .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader)
          .loadSubScript("chrome://myextension/content/script.js?foo");

// Code executed after the original file is loaded goes here
```